# Using Java Spring and CrudRepository, is it possible to insert a new row into a table without filling every column with a value?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, crud-repository

I'm working on a project where I periodically need to fill a four-column table with rows. The DB is postgresql. The columns are string1, date1, string2, date2. I have already tested the project in python with SQLAlchemy, where I filled string1 and date1 on the initial insert, and later on filled string2 and date2. Because of project logic, string2 and date2 are not available on insert, and may be updated weeks after the initial insert. With SQLAlchemy, I could simply do an insert like this:

```
row = Row(
string1 = "SomeString",
date1 = datetime.now()
)
```

I could also do this:

```
row = Row(
string1 = "SomeString",
date1 = datetime.now(),
string2 = None,
date2 = None
)
```

Now, I need to create the project in Java Spring (which I don't have much experience with), and the CrudRepository.save() method won't let me do it in either of the ways described above. It insists on having to set some sort of value for each column (corresponding to the correct datatype, as of now I'm using LocalDate for the dates, but any Date datatype will do). The workaround I have for now is setting string2 = "" and date2 = LocalDate.parse("0001-01-01"), but that is a subpar solution. I would like to send in a Null/None-value so that postgres inserts it as .

Entity as of now:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "subsets", schema = "public")
class Subsets(
    @Id
    val id: String,
    val author_created: String,
    val date_created: LocalDate,
    val author_committed: String,
    val date_committed: LocalDate,
) {
   private constructor() : this("", "", LocalDate.now(), "", LocalDate.now())
}
```

Post logic:

```
@PostMapping("/createsubset")
fun createSubset(
    @RequestParam id: String,
    @RequestParam author_created: String,
    ){
    subsetsRepository.save(
        Subsets(
            id = id,
            author_created = author_created,
            date_created = LocalDate.now(),
            author_committed = "",
            date_committed = LocalDate.parse("0001-01-01")
        )
    )

}
```

Comment: Can you show your entity class. if string2 and date2 are not annotated with @NotNull it is definitly possible to insert an entity with null values for these fields.

Comment: I have edited the question to include the entity class and the usage of the .save() method. I have also tried to put ```@Column(nullable = true)```over string2 and date2, but to no avail, it still wants me to set the values.

Comment: don't know what language this is or what version of java but I've never seen this syntax. val, fun are no keywords in java.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the model class you defined. Create a model class like the below one you can able to save data easily.

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.CreationTimestamp;
import org.hibernate.annotations.UpdateTimestamp;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(name = "subsets")
public class Subset {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "author_created", nullable = false)
    private String authorCreated;

    @Column(name = "date_created", updatable = false)
    @CreationTimestamp
    private Timestamp dateCreated;

    @Column(name = "author_committed")
    private String authorCommitted;

    @Column(name = "date_committed")
    @UpdateTimestamp
    private Timestamp dateCommitted;

    public Subset() {
    }

    public Subset(int id, String authorCreated) {
        this.id = id;
        this.authorCreated = authorCreated;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getAuthorCreated() {
        return authorCreated;
    }

    public void setAuthorCreated(String authorCreated) {
        this.authorCreated = authorCreated;
    }

    public Timestamp getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    public void setDateCreated(Timestamp dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    public String getAuthorCommitted() {
        return authorCommitted;
    }

    public void setAuthorCommitted(String authorCommitted) {
        this.authorCommitted = authorCommitted;
    }

    public Timestamp getDateCommitted() {
        return dateCommitted;
    }

    public void setDateCommitted(Timestamp dateCommitted) {
        this.dateCommitted = dateCommitted;
    }
}
```